# what does this selector mean #black_wheel.anim-wheel?

Tags: css, css-selectors

i read that #black_wheel.anim-wheel select all the #black_wheel that has anim-wheel class.
but in the following example i just have an #black_wheel. i just a little confuse about this selector.
this is my example

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Traced Bird Ad</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#logo").addClass("animated");
            $("#gradient").addClass("gradient-anim");
            $(".wheel").addClass("anim-wheel");
        });
    </script>
    <style>
    #outerWrapper {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 30px auto;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-perspective: 500px;
        -moz-perspective: 500px;
        -o-perspective: 500px;
        perspective: 500px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #logo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 37px;
        left: 39px;
        -webkit-transition: all 3s cubic-bezier(0.950, 0.050, 0.795, 0.035);
        -moz-transition: all 3s cubic-bezier(0.950, 0.050, 0.795, 0.035);
        -o-transition: all 3s cubic-bezier(0.950, 0.050, 0.795, 0.035);
        transition: all 3s cubic-bezier(0.950, 0.050, 0.795, 0.035);
        -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
        -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
        -o-transition-delay: 1s;
        transition-delay: 1s;
    }
    #swoosh {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0; 
    }
    #gradient {
        position: absolute;
        left: 1392px;
        top: 34px;  
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;    
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    #gradient.gradient-anim {
        left: 392px;
        top: 34px;  
    }
    #text {
        position: absolute;
        left: 486px;
        top: 178px; 
    }
    #black_wheel {
        position: absolute;
        left: 1434px;
        top: 10px;  
    }
    #red_wheel {
        position: absolute;
        left: 1618px;
        top: 10px;  
    }
    #silver_wheel {
        position: absolute;
        left: 1807px;
        top: 10px;  
    }
    .wheel {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition-property: left,opacity,-webkit-transform;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 3s,4s,3s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease,ease,ease-out;
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0s,.5s,0s;    
        -moz-transition-property: left,opacity,-moz-transform;
        -moz-transition-duration: 3s,4s,3s;
        -moz-transition-timing-function: ease,ease,ease-out;
        -moz-transition-delay: 0s,.5s,0s;
        -o-transition-property: left,opacity,-o-transform;
        -o-transition-duration: 3s,4s,3s;
        -o-transition-timing-function: ease,ease,ease-out;
        -o-transition-delay: 0s,.5s,0s;
        transition-property: left,opacity,transform;
        transition-duration: 3s,4s,3s;
        transition-timing-function: ease,ease,ease-out;
        transition-delay: 0s,.5s,0s;
    }
    .animated {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-720deg);    
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-720deg);    
        -o-transform: rotateY(-720deg);    
        transform: rotateY(-720deg);    
    }
    #black_wheel.anim-wheel {
        left:434px; 
    }
    #red_wheel.anim-wheel {
        left: 618px;
    }
    #silver_wheel.anim-wheel {
        left: 807px;
    }
    .anim-wheel {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-1080deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-1080deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-1080deg);
        transform: rotate(-1080deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body class="loaded">
    <div id="outerWrapper"><img src="_images/Traced%20Bird%20FMA.png" width="1000" height="260" alt="Traced Bird">
      <div id="logo"><img src="_images/birds.png" width="312" height="198" alt="logo"></div>
      <div id="swoosh"><img src="_images/swoosh.png" width="754" height="227" alt=""></div>
      <div id="gradient"><img src="_images/gradient.png" width="614" height="108" alt=""></div>
      <div id="text"><img src="_images/text.png" width="424" height="59" alt=""></div>
      <div id="black_wheel" class="wheel"><img src="_images/black_wheel.png" width="159" height="159" alt=""></div>
      <div id="red_wheel" class="wheel"><img src="_images/red_wheel.png" width="159" height="159" alt=""></div>
      <div id="silver_wheel" class="wheel"><img src="_images/silver_wheel.png" width="159" height="159" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Since IDs are unique, what `#black_wheel.anim-wheel` "means" in plain English is "the element with ID `black_wheel`, but only when it has the `anim-wheel` class.

Comment: I believe the question is more along the lines of "why is this CSS selector even in use?" If that's what you're asking, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

`#` is the prefix given to the HTML `id` attribute, and `.` is the prefix given to the HTML `class` attributes.

`#id.class` selects the element with *both* that ID and class. In your case, `#black_wheel.anim-wheel` selects the element with `id="black_wheel"` *and* `class="anim-wheel".

```html
<element id="black_wheel" class="anim-wheel"></element>
```

If the element only had the "black_wheel" `id` *or* the "anim-wheel" class, that selector wouldn't be able to select it. That element is only selected when both that `id` and `class` are present.

Check out the [W3 CSS Selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/tr/selectors) for more information.

In your example, you have the following markup for the element with that `id`:

```html
<div id="black_wheel" class="wheel"> ... </div>
```

In this state, your CSS selector will not be able to target this element as the "anim-wheel" class isn't present. **However**, on `$(document).ready()`, you have the following JavaScript which does add this class to that element:
To expand on this, you have the following JavaScript:

```js
$(".wheel").addClass("anim-wheel");
```

When this happens, that CSS selector will kick into action.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though the `#black_wheel` element is being given the `.anim-wheel` class when the page loads via jQuery as evidenced by the following line:

```
$(".wheel").addClass("anim-wheel");
```